# Change Meteor app's background on every build

Tags: node.js, meteor

Sometimes, after a change in the source code, I can't quite tell whether the built is complete and my app in browser is up to date now. Meteor's message `"=> Client modified -- refreshing (x17)` does not always allow to tell whether the message is new or stale; even if it did, my laptop has limited real estate, and just switching back and forth between text editor and browser becomes hassle enough, if done frequently.

What I'd like is an ability to change some visual attribute of the page every time the project is rebuilt or refreshed. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick hack using an inlined style tag in the body to set the whole app background color to a random string of hexadecimal digits.

HTML

```
<body>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: {{backgroundColor}};
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

JS

```
Template.body.helpers({
  backgroundColor: function(){
    return "#" + Random.hexString(6);
  }
});
```

You have to `meteor add random` to your project to access the `Random` utility.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random

Comment: Thank you! Strangely, this works for changes in html and js, but not in css. Wonder why?

Comment: When you modify CSS, Meteor does not restart/refresh server. It includes CSS right into your HTML.